# How to tell if an array of values all present in an array in a mongodb collection?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have some code that looks like this (all within the mongodb interpreter):

```
var needed_skills = ['mongodb','javascript','c++','php']

db.applicants.save( { name:'joe', skills:['c++','ruby','css'] } );
db.applicants.save( { name:'peter', skills:['mongodb','javascript','c++','php','html'] } );
```

How do I do a query that finds the applicant with all the required skills?  Basically I'm looking for documents that have all the array members present in a given array.  I know you can do something like this to find if you want it to find one member:

```
db.applicants.find({skills:'mongodb'})
```

However that is only matching one, where as I want to match all ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `$all`:

```
db.applicants.find({skills: {$all: ['mongodb','javascript','c++','php','html']} });
```

or

```
var needed_skills = ['mongodb','javascript','c++','php']

db.applicants.find({skills: {$all: needed_skills} });
```

Comment: np, updated the answer to include a shortened query that uses an array variable instead of an array literal.